# In Android 8, during video recording, how the data is saved to disk?

Tags: file-system, file-management, 8.0-oreo, 8.1-oreo, video-recording

In Android 8, during long video recording, 
1) how often does the recorded video data is written to internal storage?
2) What is the size of each piece of data written?
3) Is the data stored contiguously in the internal storage or each piece of data is stored independent of each other?

Comment: Question 1 and 2 depend on the app you are using to record video. An app developer can better tell about this. Question 3 depends on the filesystem you are writing to.

Comment: What would be the answer for a typical app such as the default app in a Samsung phone. The filesystem is sdcardfs stacked on  ext4.

Comment: I have no idea at all, but I'd use `inotify` to see live changes made by an app to filesystem.